# MFC GUI custom control: how to draw cursor updates in response to mouse moves?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc

I have a custom Windows control subclassed from `CButton` (no idea why that was selected--this is 17-year-old code; no semblance of button functionality is present).

Its `DrawItem( LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pdis )` method is called by `CButton::OnChildNotify` in response to `WM_DRAWITEM`.  It renders its scene with the `DC CDC::FromHandle( pdis->hDC )`.

The mouse event method `OnMouseMove()` calculates the new cursor position and calls `RedrawWindow( NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE )`.  A cursor that follows the mouse duly appears at the new mouse position.  It works fine, but it's slow.  In fact, only the previous and new cursor cells need be redrawn (if that) yet the graphic updates start to lag as the entire scene is rendered many times.

I thought in my `OnMouseMove()` method, instead of repainting the entire scene, could just paint the cells in question.  It already has the exact X and Y coordinates of the cells and pointers to their data.  I thought `CPaintDC(this)` would provide a `DC` that allowed this, but it doesn't paint.  (Doesn't crash either, which is a rare joy.)

My hazy recollection is that the "optimal" way to do this would be to invalidate just the areas of the two cells, and the `DrawItem()` method would eventually be told these areas were invalidated, and rather than totally repainting it could just work out from the coordinates which cells they were (not an easy operation btw) and repaint them, and that would streamline not only this cursor problem but also ensure only a few cells be painted were the partially-obscured control partially revealed.  But time pressure doesn't allow and the use cases don't seem to call for this to be optimized.

So the question is: **is there some nice way for `OnMouseMove()` to re-render a single control immediately, and if so with what `DC`?  (For instance can I cache the `DC` that I've received in `DrawItem()` via `FromHandle()?`**

Right now the only idea I have is to have an object member pointing to a single cell to be redrawn, to call RedrawWindow() with this RDW_UPDATENOW flag, and have DrawItem(), if that flag be set, do just that one item.  That would result in DrawItem() getting a DC that presumably would work in the way it always has.  Seems like a real hack though, is there a better way?

Comment: In `WM_PAINT`, the DC will be clipped by default to allow drawing only within a box that surrounds the areas that have been invalidated. `RedrawWindow()` invalidates the entire window. Use `InvalidateRect()` instead to invalidate only the areas that actually need redrawing.

Comment: OK, if I do that with the current "paint-all" DrawItem(), it will avoid instructing the graphics card to draw which I suppose would be a small benefit.  If I check for overlaps between a cell I would draw and the invalidated rect, then I could avoid calculating stuff for each cell's appearance, but I still have to loop through all cells.  Since OnMouseMove() already KNOWS what cell (it has a pointer to the cell object with its location and all pertinent info) is there no way to simply use that directly, instead of having DrawItem() loop?  (Or having much more complicated data structures?)

Comment: Don't rely on the mouse position to decide what to draw.  You can use `GetClipBox()` to get the DC's clipping box, and then just don't draw anything that is outside of the box.  Use the box's coordinates to determine which cells are inside the box, and then draw only those cells.

Comment: "using the box's coordinates to determine which cells are inside the box" requires either 1) a loop across ALL cells, inefficient for CPU (that's what I'm doing now, and is slow!), or 2) extra data structures to efficiently support mapping the clip box's left/right/top/bottom to all the cells contained therein.  That's not trivial especially as cells aren't on a grid and are of varying sizes.  I'm trying to think how you'd even do it without going O(n).   That's why I'm asking how to make use of the fact I already have found a pointer to the exact cell object to be redrawn.

Comment: you cant rely on that, for the simple fact that if (a portion of) your window is ever covered by another window and then re- exposed, your window has to redraw the area that was covered. That has nothing to do with which cell is currently selected. For that matter, how do you determine which cell is under the mouse during moves and clicks, without eating a lot of time and resources? That requires some kind of hit testing to map coordinates to cells. That same logic can then be applied to drawing regions, too

Comment: The existing "paint everything" DrawItem() is slow but acceptable for exposure events which are quite rare.  In a perfect world I'd have time to polish that but it's not a priority.  I'll note your excellent advice and tips on that for later.  The case I want to optimize is response to mouse movements which are quite constant.  It is easy enough to translate a single X/Y coord to a specific window but I don't see a surefire way to do that for translating a region to a set of windows, that isn't ultimately an O(n) traverse albeit perhaps of a portion of the list instead of full.

Comment: A [CPaintDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpaintdc-class) *"object can only be used when responding to a `WM_PAINT` message"*. Of course you cannot use it in your `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler. What you can do in your `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler is to calculate your grid cursor position, call into your implementation to set it, and have that implementation update the previous (if any) as well as the new cell, if the grid cursor position is different from the previous grid cursor position.

Comment: You've helped me out before IInspecable, glad to see you again!  OK by "calculate your grid cursor position" you mean the rect of the cell?  Sure, I have it (don't have to calculate, I've found the cell that holds it and it has that as a member).  By "implementation update the previous (if any) as well as the new cell" you mean invalidate?  OK, easy enough.  But then the DrawItem() is called and has to work back from the rect to figure out which item it is, and that is inefficient.  Since the MouseMove has found the exact cell object already, I don't want DrawItem() to have to find it again.

Comment: The rule to exclusively render in response to `WM_PAINT` is a rule of thumb, really. When following it there's not much you need to take into account. Everything just works, efficiently, too. You *can* render outside `WM_PAINT`, too, as long as your `WM_PAINT` handler and the out-of-band rendering produce identical visuals (if they don't, you'll get flickering, an inconsistent UI, and a confused user). If you want to render in response to `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, grab a [CClientDC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cclientdc-class) and perform your rendering (restoring the ...

Comment: ... previously highlighted cell, as well as rendering the new highlight). You may want to apply an appropriate clipping region, although that is not strictly required. You will have to make sure to register for [WM_MOUSELEAVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mouseleave) messages, too, so that a highlighted cell gets restored when moving outside the control.

Comment: Thanks again Mr. IInspecable!  Added five lines and performance now apparently instantaneous.  Yes, appearance is identical as the DrawItem() method called a subroutine to draw a single item--which I now call directly.  ClientDC( this ) was the answer to my question.  If you answer thus I'll upvote, otherwise I'll answer myself in a day.  BTW I handled ON_WM_MOUSELEAVE() long ago, otherwise the brute-force method would have the same abandoned cursor problem you warn about.  But to get MOUSELEAVE events, I needed _TrackMouseEvent() upon initial (and first subsequent to a leave) CMOUSEMOVE.

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows application, it is customary to perform all rendering in response to a [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-paint) (or [`WM_NCPAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-ncpaint)) message. Code that needs to trigger a repaint marks part or all of window's client area as dirty, by calling [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) (and friends). The system is optimized for this approach, coalescing multiple requests into a single update region, and subsequently issuing a `WM_PAINT` message, when there is no more important work to do (like handling input).

This works reliably, and is usually easier to implement than spreading the rendering across several places. It is, however, perfectly legal to deviate from this, and perform rendering anywhere in your code. While `WM_PAINT` messages can still arrive at any time, it is desirable to have the out-of-band rendering produce identical visual results as the `WM_PAINT` handler would, to prevent visual artifacts.

All rendering goes through an abstraction called a [device context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/device-contexts) (DC). When handling a `WM_PAINT` message in an MFC application, a suitable DC can be obtained by constructing a [`CPaintDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpaintdc-class) instance. When rendering anywhere else you cannot use a `CPaintDC`, but need to use a [`CClientDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cclientdc-class) instead (or a [`CWindowDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwindowdc-class), to render the non-client area as well). In general, rendering code need not know, which type of DC it is rendering to, and can usually be reused without change.